# Did congress increase the U.S. Capitol Police budget by $2 Billion?

Tags: united-states, congress, budget, police

I've seen a discussion that implies there was a vote to increase the Capitol Police budget by $2 Billion, while the DC metropolitan police budget has been cut.  It is also being suggested that the Capitol Police is opening field offices around the country!  Is that accurate?

https://thehill.com/homenews/house/565384-house-passes-spending-bill-to-boost-capitol-police-and-hill-staffer-pay

In reviewing the testimony of the Capitol Police inspector general, it seemed he was indicating that the failures inside the capitol were failures of leadership (including orders NOT to use less lethal crowd control measures) and insufficient funds.

Comment: See https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/66229/why-is-the-capitol-police-expanding-nationally-when-we-already-have-the-fbi/66231#66231 regarding the field offices.

Comment: The sourced article states: *The bill would provide $604 million for the Capitol Police, an increase of $88 million from the enacted level for this year.* There is no source for the Metropolitan Police Department budget, The last paragraph is also unsourced.

Answer (score 8):

**No.**

According to [another article](https://thehill.com/homenews/senate/565049-senators-reach-2-billion-deal-on-emergency-capitol-security-bill):

> The deal, which is expected to be just over $2 billion, will include
> $100 million for the Capitol Police and more than $300 million for the
> security measures around the Capitol complex, according to a source
> familiar with the agreement.
>
> The deal will include more than $1 billion for the Pentagon, divided
> up between the money for the National Guard and roughly $500 million
> for the Afghan special immigrant visas program. The State Department
> would get an additional $600 million for the program and the
> Department of Health and Human Services Office of Refugee Resettlement
> would get $25 million, the source added.

So it's way less than 2G$ for the *Capitol Police*.

Comment: **Another provision would direct the Architect of the Capitol to procure a plaque that “commends the examples of bravery and service-above-self”**. Maybe that's where the $2B will go. :)